# Bring Node.js console window to the front

Tags: node.js

When running a Node.js app in a console, is there a way to bring the console window to the front programmatically, from within the app itself?

I am primarily interested in doing so in Windows, using the latest Node.js (v13 atm)

And if there is a package that can do so, that would be good enough.

**Scenario**

Running multiple Node.js consoles. When something important happens in one of them, bring the window up front. I haven't been able to find any library or example for it.

Comment: There's nothing like that built into node.js.  You'd have to find a native code module that does that on Windows.  I'm not aware of one.

Comment: Yes, using batch-scripting, you can look at this answer for inspiration https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557166/bring-to-front-for-windows-xp-command-shell

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR;** [bringToFront](https://github.com/Estradiaz/bringToFront)

---

### Use Node.js [N-API](https://nodejs.org/api/n-api.html)

#### The basic idea is to use the windows api to controll the window states.

One can use [`SetForegroundWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setforegroundwindow).

But there are some [restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-allowsetforegroundwindow#remarks):

> - The process is the foreground process.
> - The process was started by the foreground process.
> - The process received the last input event.
> - There is no foreground process.
> - The foreground process is being debugged.
> - The foreground is not locked (see LockSetForegroundWindow).
> - The foreground lock time-out has expired (see SPI_GETFOREGROUNDLOCKTIMEOUT in SystemParametersInfo).
> - No menus are active.

To workaround those restrictions one can programatically simulate userinput:

- press alt key (think of e.g.: `alt+tab`):
- `keybd_event(VK_MENU, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | 0, 0);`
- now bring to front
- `SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);`
- release key
- `keybd_event(VK_MENU, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);`

  ---

copy of main logic for stack**overflow**:

```js
    #include "./pidToFront.h"
    #include <windows.h>

    using namespace v8;

    void SetForegroundWindowInternal(HWND hWnd)
    {
        if(!::IsWindow(hWnd)) return;

        BYTE keyState[256] = {0};
        //to unlock SetForegroundWindow we need to imitate Alt pressing
        if(::GetKeyboardState((LPBYTE)&keyState))
        {
            if(!(keyState[VK_MENU] & 0x80))
            {
                ::keybd_event(VK_MENU, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | 0, 0);
            }
        }

        ::SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);

        if(::GetKeyboardState((LPBYTE)&keyState))
        if(::GetKeyboardState((LPBYTE)&keyState))
        if(::GetKeyboardState((LPBYTE)&keyState))
        {
            if(!(keyState[VK_MENU] & 0x80))
            {
                ::keybd_event(VK_MENU, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
            }
        }
    }

    HWND g_HWND=NULL;
    BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProcMy(HWND hwnd,LPARAM lParam)
    {
        DWORD lpdwProcessId;
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd,&lpdwProcessId);
        if(lpdwProcessId==lParam)
        {
            g_HWND=hwnd;
            return FALSE;
        }
        return TRUE;
    }
    void win32js::toFront(const Nan::FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& info){
        Local<Context> context = info.GetIsolate()->GetCurrentContext();
        if(info.Length() < 1 || !info[0]->IsNumber()){
            Nan::ThrowTypeError("Invalid argument expected pid as number");
        }

        LPARAM pid = info[0]->NumberValue(context).FromJust();
        if(EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProcMy, (double)pid)){
            info.GetReturnValue().Set(-2);
        }
        if(g_HWND > 0){
            SetForegroundWindow(g_HWND);
            if(GetForegroundWindow() == g_HWND){
                info.GetReturnValue().Set((double)(unsigned long)g_HWND);
                g_HWND = NULL;
                return;
            }
            SetForegroundWindowInternal(g_HWND);
            if(GetForegroundWindow() == g_HWND){
                info.GetReturnValue().Set((double)(unsigned long)g_HWND);
                g_HWND = NULL;
                return;
            }
        } else {
            info.GetReturnValue().Set(-1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to use this in Node.js JavaScript, but I will try :)

Comment: On Windows 10, I can see it only flashing the window icon in the task bar, but without bringing it up.

Comment: I do the same here, on Windows 10. I run it in the console, then click away. It only flashes the icon, but doesn't bring the window up. And yes, it does find the window.

Comment: Using the latest, not getting any further than just a blinking icon.

Comment: @vitaly-t ok this time it works for sure - hacked key press into it, changed repo

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that example works. Would you like to update the answer, and remove what's no longer relevant? Thank you for the repo! I hope you will decide to maintain it ;)

Comment: Thanks! I used `robotjs` to get around the restrictions you listed by send a key down before calling `SetForegroundWindow()` and a key up event after.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this the answer to your question but it looks like this could resolve your problem: [Setting focus to a Windows application from Node-JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39421074/setting-focus-to-a-windows-application-from-node-js)

Sorry if this is wrong.

Comment: Can't use that. That's based on now abandoned `ffi` module. I was able to install it specifically under Node.js v8, and nothing else. Doesn't even install under v6, v10, v12, v13. In all, it is useless.